# Filtered reports

Tags: reporting

We have a requirement to send a Oppty report filtered by Account region.

I am just trying to write down the synopsis of my requirement:
We have a custom region picklist field on the Account object; (values: USA, EMEA, APAC, CANLA)
We need to send a report to regional sales manager with only their opportunites.

Is it possible to implement this functionality with a single report with filters, and each regional sales manager should see only their opptys.?

When you apply a filter in a report and send it, will the filters still be applied on the report? 
I have read in some article relating to dashboard, if you email a dashboard with filters, only the unfiltered data will be seen when the users open the dashbaord via email. So i am lil confused with the reports.. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Does those opportunities are shared only to some users?

Comment: Yes.. that's right....

Comment: than if there are good sharing rules on Opportunities managers should see only those from thier own team/regin.

Comment: Are you planning on making this a scheduled report? If you plan on having the users run the report themselves, Birthus is totally correct. The one caveat being that if you are planning on scheduling it, the running user will determine the level of access.

Comment: If you need to distribute as Excel attachments, I'd suggest looking at Conga Composer/Conductor or perhaps Conga Courier.  You can set it up so that you build 1 query - to locate all the recipients, and then Conga will schedule and execute the same Opportunities report passing in the value of each query result recipient as a report filter parameter. As you add sales managers, nothing needs to change.  I used this approach to send out weekly Leads reports to partners where we had 60-100 partners and they came and went over time (we were too cheap for Partner Portal)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to schedule sending of this report - you'll have to provide the running user. Report will be run on that user's privileges (so if System Administrator is selected - all opportunities will be sent out). Essentially a snapshot is taken and sent.

Report filters will be preserved, it's only the dashboard filters that aren't.

I think you'll have to make copies of that report and schedule them separately for each team. In that case it won't matter much whether you'll specify an user from appropriate region (and rely on sharing) or change the region filter (and rely on that)...

One way or another - scheduled reports used to be limited to first 2,000 rows and sent as HTML (I'd prefer an excel attachment). Not sure if anything has changed in that area. Keep that in mind if you're still willing to schedule them.